# Index-Match formula to look for every 6th cell in a column

Tags: excel

Is it possible to set the following Index-Match formula to look for every 6th value in the column E? Perhaps it's just the matter of using OFFSET?

Current formula:

```
=INDEX(E2:E10,MATCH(1,(C13=C2:C10)*(D13=D2:D10),0))
```

I have 3 columns,

```
Column D    C     E
    2.30%   3   £3,868.86 
    2.30%   10  £3,736.99 
    2.30%   3   £3,868.86 
    2.30%   2   £3,906.51 
    2.30%   5   £3,807.84 
    2.30%   2   £3,906.51 
    2.30%   10  £3,736.99 
    2.30%   2   £3,906.51 
    2.30%   2   £3,906.51 
    2.30%   5   £3,807.84 
    2.30%   5   £3,807.84 
    2.30%   10  £3,736.99 
    2.30%   3   £3,868.86 
    1.30%   3   £3,685.60
```

I am using Index and Match function to find which Interest Rate and Deposit % leads to Result in Column E. I need to use my formula on every 6th cell, which will then display selected cells from Column E in any other column.

Comment: your question is not clear. You have not used column A in your formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Firstly, there is no such thing as "Column A6" so I have presumed that you mean Column A. If you actually mean "From A6 down..." then let me know and I will have to update my answer.*

Put this in any cell and drag down

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$100,(ROW(A1)-1)*6,1)
```

Alternatively, with `OFFSET`

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MAX((ROW(A1)-1)*6-1,0),0)
```

I'm on a roll now, so with `INDIRECT`

```
=INDIRECT("A"&MAX((ROW(A1)-1)*6,1))
```

Comment: It doesn't work with '=INDEX(E2:E10,MATCH(1,(C13=C2:C10)*(D13=D2:D10),0))', causes 'REF' error.

Comment: What is that formula? Not one I suggested?

Comment: It's the formula where I need to implement your proposed solution. So it only retrieves every 6th cell value.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how that is implementing my solution. Do you have the values in column A? If so just paste either of these formulas into B1 and drag down

Comment: Your proposed formula works independently, but it doesn't retrieve the first value in A1, instead, shows 'REF' error.

Comment: Thank you, would you happen to know how to implement it with the outlined formula in the question, and whether it is possible to achieve?

Comment: Rather than the example data, update your question for what's in columns E, C & D and then I can say

Comment: I've updated the question, does this make it more clear?

Comment: I can successfully implement it as follows, =INDEX(E2:E10,(ROW(E2)-1)*6)MATCH(1,(C13=C2:C10)*(D13=D2:D10),0)) but the moment I add missing -1 from your Index formula, it causes error.

Comment: I think it should be `ROW(S1)` to work. But if you've got it working nevermind, I'm pleased. Don't forget to upvote helpful answers and also accept answers that help you to solve your question.

Comment: CallumDa, I've just noticed, the aforementioned formula returns #REF for the last cell, is there a way to avoid this error? It for some reason skips the last number.